# Multiplication of two vectors with a real number

Tags: vectors

I was training on online exercises about scalar products, and i came across this problem :

*In an orthonormal frame (O;i;j) we give the points A (-3;1), B(2;4), u= 3i + 2j, ...*

*5 ) Calculate the scalar product : BA.2u*

The website actually give the answer : -42, but i can't find a way to reach it.

**What i have done and tried :**

I found BA(5;-3)

Then using the formula : u.v=xx'+yy'

I found : 5x(2x3)+(-3x(2x2)) = 18

I am obviously missing something, maybe a rule, if anyone can help me out on this, i would really appreciate it

Good day to everyone !

Comment: It's $BA=(-5,-3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$BA = (-5,-3)$.  To go from $B$ to $A$, we must subtract $5$ from $2$ to get $-3$ and subtract $3$ from $4$ to get $1$.  It is odd that you got the second coordinate correct, but not the first.

Then $(-5,-3)\cdot 2(3,2) = (-5,-3)\cdot(6,4) = -30 -12 = -42$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I actually checked BA 3 or 4 times, i don't know why i made the same mistake over and over. But now i know and i will be more careful. Thanks again !